# Property 'favoriteIds' does not exist on type 'Promise'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Help. I have a problem Property 'favoriteIds' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: string | null; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; } | null>'.ts(2339)
any

```
export default async function getFavoriteListings(){
try{
    const currentUser = getCurrentUser();
    if(!currentUser)
    return [];
    const favorites = await prisma.listing.findMany({
        where: {
            id: {
                in: [...(currentUser.favoriteIds || [])]
            }
        }
    });
}catch(error)
```

}
Prisma

```
 model User 
    id             String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    name           String?
    email          String?   @unique
    emailVerified  DateTime?
    image          String?
    hashedPassword String?
    createdAt      DateTime  @default(now())
    updatedAt      DateTime  @updatedAt
    favoriteIds    String[]  @db.ObjectId

    accounts     Account[]
    listings     Listing[]
    reservations Reservation[]
```

Comment: You probably forgot to await `getCurrentUser()`, i.e. `await getCurrentUser()`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot it. Thank you, I find it by myself yesterday. But anyway, thank you